# Create x axis labels for dodged subgroup in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

I am trying to have this barplot use the data from column `SPP` as the x axis labels rather than `funct_form`, but unsure how to do this.

data sample:

```
top32reads <- structure(list(identifier = 1:10, SPP = c("Penstemon", "Rosaceae Group 1", 
"Abies", "Hypericum", "Saxifraga OR Micranthes OR Boykinia", 
"Eriogonum", "Vaccinium", "Oenothera", "Oxyria digyna", "Chamerion"
), max = c(0.520063568, 0.479127183, 0.503981446, 0.717687654, 
0.434079314, 0.362801825, 0.191388889, 0.219305556, 0.263381525, 
0.383032052), readsum = c(6.716942576, 5.503499137, 3.881683753, 
3.798417906, 3.49976764, 2.309000619, 1.913782497, 1.616440058, 
1.59921115, 1.478810665), funct_type = c("Forb", "Forb", "Conifer", 
"Forb", "Forb", "Forb", "Shrub", "Forb", "Forb", "Forb"), frequencyformula = c(52L, 
50L, 40L, 45L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 43L, 40L, 41L), frequency = c(1, 
0.961538462, 0.769230769, 0.865384615, 0.903846154, 0.903846154, 
0.884615385, 0.826923077, 0.769230769, 0.788461538)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

barplot code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(scales)
library(colorspace)

top32reads%>%
  mutate(funct_type = fct_reorder(.f = funct_type, .x = -readsum, min),
         main_color = brewer_pal("qual")(n_distinct(funct_type))[funct_type]
  ) %>%
  group_by(funct_type) %>% 
  mutate(lvl = as.integer(fct_reorder(SPP, readsum)),
         relvl = rescale(lvl, c(0, .6), from = c(0, max(length(lvl), 5))),
         sub_color = darken(main_color, relvl)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = funct_type, y = readsum)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = sub_color),
           position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  ylab("Sum of read percentages across samples") +
  xlab("OTUs Consumed by Functional Type") +
  ggtitle("Diet by Relative Read Abundance") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 18, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 28, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

when i try to switch out `SPP` for `funct_type` in `aes()`, (also adding `axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)`) I end up with this
[image]

which obviously does not have the same ordering and spacing as previously

Comment: The example is missing `fct_reorder()` and therefore variable `sub_color`.

Comment: i'm afraid i don't follow you

Comment: Line 6 of your example uses `fct_reorder()` which is not included in `base` or `dplyr` or `ggplot2`.

Comment: oh sorry. ```library(forcats)```

Comment: The key is to swap `funct_type` with `SPP` in ggplot, e.g. `ggplot(top32reads, aes(x = SPP, y = readsum)) +` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not trivial. I think user Jamie's idea of using facets is very good +1. But it requires a bit more work on the underlying ordered factors. You have already created an ordered factor by function type (well done), but then you did not make use of it as your x variable. Do it!

You will see, I have retained the function type labels (as strips in the facets. You can also completely remove them, (using theme), and if you want more space between your funcion types, increase the strip spacing with `panel.spacing`. I've removed a lot of unnecessary code for the problem. Some comments in the code.

```
## when doing complex data wrangling, 
## I prefer to first create a proper object 
## instead of piping into ggplot directly
df_fct <-
top32reads %>%
  mutate(funct_type = fct_reorder(.f = funct_type, .x = -readsum, min),
         main_color = brewer_pal("qual")(n_distinct(funct_type))[funct_type]
  ) %>%
  group_by(funct_type) %>% 
  ## don't convert your factor to integer yet
  mutate(lvl = fct_reorder(SPP, desc(readsum)),
  ## but only now
         relvl = rescale(as.integer(lvl), c(0, .6), from = c(0, max(length(lvl), 5))),
         sub_color = darken(main_color, relvl), 
  ## this is just one suggestion to reformat the labels. 
  ## There are other ways to deal with the long labels 
  ## e.g., user jamie has flipped the coordinates which I find a good idea
  spp_lab = factor(lvl, levels = levels(lvl), labels = gsub(" ", "\n", levels(lvl)))) 
  
ggplot(df_fct , aes(x = spp_lab , y = readsum)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = sub_color),
           position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  ## facet by funct_type, switch strip to bottom
  facet_grid(~funct_type, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  ## place strip outside
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Comment: I just finally got around to doing this with my larger dataset (29 SPP & 4 Forms) and only one category of ```funct_type``` (Forb) is in color scale, the others are all black. Any thoughts on a fix for that?

Comment: any idea on why the color scale might be getting all messed up @tjebo ? I tried going down some rabbit holes to fix it but have not been able to figure it out.  Pretty new to this over here.

Comment: @sscoresby I think the most likely is that this happens when converting your levels into colors. Please check if "main_color" are all proper colors? and is the "relvl" column all numeric? And is the "sub_color" columns also proper colors?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know how to check those things. Currently googling up a storm trying to figure it out though...

Comment: @sscoresby check the data! in particular `df_fct `. Check the column classes with `str(df_fct )` and check the values either by skimming through or for example with `unique(df_fct$column_of_interest)`. What I mean with "proper colors" is that your values should all be in the format `"#abcdef"` whereby those can be letters and numbers. It should not be `"#xyxyxy"`, where the same xx or xy are repeated three times, because those would be grey values.

Comment: ```main_color``` are correct values for the ```Forbs```, but all others are #FFFF99, which align with ```sub_color``` value of #000000! All of these 0 values have ```relvl``` of >2, all correct values <1.

 When I changed ```sub_color = darken``` to ```sub_color = lighten```, those values change to #FFFFFF.  I was able to get some colors back (but not the gradient) by changing ```relvl = rescale(as.integer(lvl), c(0, 0.6)``` to ```relvl = rescale(as.integer(lvl), c(0, 0.1)```

Comment: @sscoresby The default palette in brewer_pal(type = "qual") will give a very bright yellowish color (check `scales::show_col(brewer_pal("qual")(4))`). I guess the way `colorspace::darken` works that it somehow equalises the pairs in the color hex code (that's just my gut feeling and no idea if this is true). A solution would be to either (like you did) reduce the range from rescale , or to use different colors altogether. I personally like "Set1" for qualitative data - just use `brewer_pal(palette = "Set1")`

Answer (score 1):

**Revised Answer**

If you want to keep everything the same but use `SPP` for the x-axis you just need to update the ggplot call. e.g.

```
ggplot(aes(x = SPP, y = readsum))
```

And you can use `coord_flip` to rotate the axes.

Which gets you this.

[image]

**Old Answer**

Is this what you're thinking? I removed some of the extra styling you had for demonstrative purposes. Also it's helpful in the future to include all the packages that you're using for the reprex.

You can use `facet_wrap` to display different groups which in this case are shown at the top. Then use `SPP` as your x variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(scales)
library(colorspace)

top32reads = top32reads %>%
  mutate(funct_type = fct_reorder(.f = funct_type, .x = -readsum, min),
         main_color = brewer_pal("qual")(n_distinct(funct_type))[funct_type]
  ) %>%
  group_by(funct_type) %>% 
  mutate(lvl = as.integer(fct_reorder(SPP, readsum)),
         relvl = rescale(lvl, c(0, .6), from = c(0, max(length(lvl), 5))),
         sub_color = darken(main_color, relvl)) %>%
  ungroup()

top32reads %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = SPP, y = readsum)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = sub_color),
           position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  ylab("Sum of read percentages across samples") +
  xlab("OTUs Consumed by Functional Type") +
  ggtitle("Diet by Relative Read Abundance") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ funct_type) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: oo wow very fancy, but far fancier than i had in mind. I really just want to maintain the format i had but just... with those ```SPP``` labels on the x axis rather than the ```funct_type``` labels.

Comment: and ty re: packages used. i am just revisiting this code so forgot which packages i had used.

Comment: ah I see. Then all you need to do is use `SPP` instead of `funct_type` in your `aes()` call

Comment: i tried that, unfortunately. see edits...